# PLCC4 footprint how to connect LED

Tags: led, diodes, active-components, white

I am confused as to how I should be connecting this design since this LED LTW-E670DS since it has 4 pins.

How do I connect it? [image]

Pin 2 is Anode and 1 Cathode but 3 and 4?

Answer (score 1):

3 and 4 are connected to 1, so they are also connected to the Cathode. Possibly at lower currents, you don't need to connect all of them. But if it's not stated on the datasheet I would connect all of them.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That clears up

Comment: without looking at the datasheet, I would guess you want to connect 1, 3, and 4 directly to a large 0V plane, for heat sink purposes.